# Date saves to mysql database as 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code snipet here:

```
    // Insert data into mysql 
     $data = "'".date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $data3)))."'";
     echo $data;
     $sql="INSERT INTO assets(dateOfPurchase) VALUES ('$data')";
     $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2015-10-11'
```

Kindly help me sort it out.

Comment: Edit your question to show `$sql` after the variable substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that you have the single quotes appearing twice, once in the definition of `$date`, once in the query.  You only need to include them once:

```
 $data = "'".date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/',        $data3)))."'";
echo $data;
 $sql="INSERT INTO assets(dateOfPurchase) VALUES ($data)";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Your more serious problems are:

- You are using "mysql_" functions, which are no longer supported.
- You should not be putting parameters directly into query strings.  You should be using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are adding extra quotes. Use it like this:

```
$data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/',        $data3)));

$sql = "INSERT INTO assets(dateOfPurchase) VALUES ('$data')";
```